# The complete solution to a system of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics, real-algebraic-geometry

If I am solving a positive-dimensional system of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$, and specifically am searching only for real solutions, how do I know that my solution is complete and there are no other possibilities?  For example, consider the system:

$$x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$$

I can solve it by letting $x_1 = t \in [-1,1]$, then $x_2 = \pm \sqrt{1-t^2}$ and I'm golden.  As far as I know there are no more real solutions that are unique (excluding the one that is the same up to the choice of parameter).  But how do I know that?  When the system gets more complicated, is there a nice way to figure it out?

I'd be interested in a general proof over an arbitrary field as well.  However, I suspect my life is going to be made harder because I am working with the real solutions only, and as a result there are solutions over the field extension that I don't consider.

Specifically, the equations are:

$$f\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i4} - K1 = 0$$

$$f\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i3}x_{i2} - K_2 = 0$$

$$f\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i1}x_{i3} - K_3 = 0$$

$$f\sum_{i=1}^n p_{z1}x_{i2}x_{i3} + f\sum_{i=1}^np_{y1}x_{i1}x_{13} - K_4 = 0$$

$$f\sum_{i=1}^n p_{z1}x_{i4} - f\sum_{i=1}^np_{x1}x_{i1}x_{13} - K_5 = 0$$

$$f\sum_{i=1}^n -p_{y1}x_{i4} - f\sum_{i=1}^np_{z1}x_{i1}x_{13} - K_6 = 0$$

along with the "circularity equations":

$$x_{i1}^2 + x_{12}^2 = 1$$

$$x_{i3}^2 + x_{14}^2 = 1$$

where $f \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $K_j \in \mathbb{R}$ (there is technically another set of circularity equations but they are on variables that do not appear in the above system).

Comment: For your example, also $x_2=-\sqrt{1-t^2}$ works.

Comment: In general, the set of (real) solutions to a system of polynomial equations can be horrible. Very often it is not even parametrizable; systems with parametrizable solution spaces are generally considered to be very nice. If there are particular constraints to the systems you are considering, like the dimension, number of equations or their degrees, that would be very much worth mentioning.

Comment: To your first comment: I agree, edited.  To the second, I luckily have a very nice system that I'm working on in particular.  I would like to know if there is any way to know that I'm done finding solutions.

Comment: Then I suggest you share this system, or whatever properties make it very nice, because (as far as I know) there is no general way to know that you're done.

Comment: I didn't see your edit.  I have 6 + 3n equations and 9n variables, where n is an integer.  I have one linear equation, five equations that are bilinear or trilinear in their variables*, and the 3n equations are quadratics in two variables (they are actually just the above equation whose solution is the unit circle, so I can assume that those are nice and solved).  I'm not sure though how that might help.

*they are bilinear with one parameter, or trilinear if I allow the parameter to itself be a variable.

Comment: If all equations are at most quadratic, then the solution space can be parametrized very cleanly. If I understand correctly you have five bilinear equations, which form a linear family on one parameter?

Comment: I believe that is correct, yes (sorry for the lack of mathematical formalism, I'm a bit new to this).  The equations are of the form: $f \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i - K = 0$, where $K \in \mathbb{R}$, or are otherwise very similar.  There are 5 such equations, and each one has the same parameter, $f$.

Comment: I suggest you describe your system in the question body itself. With something concrete to refer to and work with, I'm confident I can explain how to find all solutions and verify *that* these are all solutions.

Comment: Done.  Looking at them now, I was mistaken.  The last three equations of the "big six" are trilinear, but they have nearly the same form.

Comment: I see $4n$ variables of the form $x_{ij}$, and then $p_{x1}$, $p_{y1}$ and $p_{z1}$. Are these $3$ more variables?

Comment: That is correct. The remaining $2n$ variables exist only in a set of $n$ circularity equations and don't otherwise show up in this system, so I consider them to be solved.  The notation $p$ comes from the application itself (which is robotics, where the $p$ represents a position vector), but the $x_{ij}$ and $p$ variables are treated the same mathematically

Comment: The problem is clear now, thank you. Can it happen that $K_i=0$ for some $i$? This possibility forces one to distinguish a **lot** of cases, it would be nice if that could be avoided, at least in part.

Comment: Hmm... Actually, the case I care about is k = 0 except K3, which is a positive real number. The general case can be left to later that's the most important one

Comment: Let me point out that in the general situation, if one is dealing with a semi-algebraic functions over $\Bbb R$ or another real-closed field as you are here, you can (attempt to) compute a [cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition) which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer ended up becoming rather much longer than I had hoped, even though I have omitted quite some details. So first I'd like to remark on your original question about general systems of polynomial equations. In the comments I said solving your system is relatively easy because it concerns only polynomials of low degree (in fact it it reduces to a system of equations of degree at most $2$). In spite of my unpleasantly long and cumbersome answer I stand by this comment; in general, solving systems with (many) polynomials of higher degrees is a very ad hoc matter, and is more often than not practically intractible.

---

In finding all solutions I'll assume familiarity with basic linear algebra; some vector and matrix notation, and solving systems of linear equations. Let ${\bf1}_n=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\Bbb{R}^n$, let $K_i':=\tfrac{K_i}{f}$ and define $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in\Bbb{R}^n$ as
$$x_j:=(x_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq n}.$$
This allows us to write down the system of six equations more concisely and transparently. Rewriting a bit and substituting the first two equations into the last three, the system becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle x_4,{\bf1}\rangle&=&K_1',\\
\langle x_2,x_3\rangle&=&K_2',\\
\langle x_1,x_3\rangle&=&K_3',\\
p_{z1}K_2'+p_{y1}x_{13}\langle x_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&K_4',\\
p_{z1}K_1'+p_{x1}x_{13}\langle x_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&K_5',\\
p_{y1}K_1'+p_{z1}x_{13}\langle x_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&-K_6'.
\end{eqnarray*}
What is most striking is that, apart from the coefficient $x_{13}$ in the last three equations, these equations concern the $x_j$ only in terms of inner products! Also note that the variables $x_{24},\ldots,x_{n4}$ appear only in the first equation, which is linear and hence easy to solve. So will omit the first equation from now on.

First we treat some boundary cases. If $x_{14}=\pm1$ then $x_3=0$ and the system of equations becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
0&=&K_2',\\
0&=&K_3',\\
0&=&K_4',\\
p_{z1}K_1'&=&K_5',\\
p_{y1}K_1'&=&-K_6'.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is a linear system of equations, having solutions (with $x_{14}=\pm1$) if and only if if $K_i'=0$ for all $i$, or $K_2'=K_3'=K_4'=0$ and $K_1'\neq0$. Similarly, if $x_{12}=\pm1$ then $x_1=0$ and the system of equations becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle x_2,x_3\rangle&=&K_2',\\
0&=&K_3',\\
p_{z1}K_2'&=&K_4',\\
p_{z1}K_1'&=&K_5',\\
p_{y1}K_1'&=&-K_6'.
\end{eqnarray*}
For any choice of $x_{22},\ldots,x_{n2}\in\Bbb{R}$ this is again a linear system. There are no solutions (with $x_{12}=\pm1$) if and only if $K_1'K_4'\neq K_2'K_5'$, or $K_2'=0$ and $K_4'\neq0$, or $K_1'=0$ and $K_5'\neq0$ or $K_6'\neq0$.

Now let $x_{12},x_{14}\in(-1,1)$. It follows from the circularity equations that for all $i$
$$x_{i1}=\pm\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x_{i3}=\pm\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}.$$
Hence $x_{i1}=\pm x_{11}$ and $x_{i3}=\pm x_{13}$ for all $i$, so there exist unique vectors $e_1,e_3\in\Bbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$x_1=\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}\ e_1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x_3=\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\ e_3,$$
and all their coefficients are either $1$ or $-1$. We may now rewrite the equations as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\langle x_2,e_3\rangle&=&K_2',\\
\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}\langle e_1,e_3\rangle&=&K_3',\\
p_{z1}K_2'+p_{y1}e_{13}\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\langle e_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&K_4',\\
p_{z1}K_1'+p_{x1}e_{13}\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\langle e_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&K_5',\\
p_{y1}K_1'+p_{z1}e_{13}\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\langle e_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&-K_6'.
\end{eqnarray*}
This eliminates $x_1$ and $x_3$ and leaves only $e_1$, $e_3$ in stead in these equations. First consider the case that $m:=\langle e_1,e_3\rangle\neq0$. Then by the second equation we have $K_3'\neq0$, and it can be written as
$$\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}=\frac{K_3'}{m},$$
which shows that we must have $\tfrac{K_3'}{m}\in[-1,1]$, or equivalently $|K_3'|<|m|$. In particular we must have $|K_3'|<n$ for solutions to exist at all, as $|m|\leq n$. So let's assume that $|K_3'|<n$, and choose $e_1$ and $e_3$ such that $|K_3'|<|m|$. Counting the number of pairs for which this holds as a function of $K_3'$ is a nice combinatorial problem that is suited for a question of it's own, though it is not complicated.

The first equation is now a linear equation for $x_{22},\ldots,x_{n2}\in\Bbb{R}$. Substituting the second equation into the last three yields the system
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{1-x_{14}^2}\sqrt{1-x_{12}^2}\langle e_1,e_3\rangle&=&K_3',\\
p_{z1}K_2'+p_{y1}e_{13}\frac{K_3'}{\langle e_1,e_3\rangle}\langle e_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&K_4',\\
p_{z1}K_1'+p_{x1}e_{13}\frac{K_3'}{\langle e_1,e_3\rangle}\langle e_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&K_5',\\
p_{y1}K_1'+p_{z1}e_{13}\frac{K_3'}{\langle e_1,e_3\rangle}\langle e_1,{\bf1}_n\rangle&=&-K_6',
\end{eqnarray*}
which are then also linear equations in $p_{x1},p_{y1},p_{z1}\in\Bbb{R}$, where there are unfortunately a lot of cases to distinguis. The first equation simply tells us that
$$x_{14}^2=1-\frac{K_3'^2}{(1-x_{12}^2)\langle e_1,e_3\rangle^2},$$
which determines $x_{14}$ up to sign.

Finally, consider the case that $\langle e_1,e_3\rangle=0$. Note that this is only possible if $n$ is even. Then $K_3'=0$ and the second equation is obsolete. For each of the $2^n$ choices for $e_1$ there are $\tbinom{n}{\tfrac{n}{2}}$ choices for $e_3$, by changing the signs of precisely half of all coordinates of $e_1$. For every choice of $x_{12},x_{14}\in\Bbb{R}$ the remaining equations are again linear, and there are a lot of cases to distinguish as before.

Comment: This is outstanding I know comments aren't supposed to be for this, but thanks!